# How to get URL segment in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have URL's in project as:

> http://blo.c/news 
>   http://blo.c/video

How I can get segments `news`, `video` from these URL?

I tried to use `$location` in Angular JS, but this object has not these segments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$location.path()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

```
// given url http://blo.c/news
var path = $location.path();
// => "/news"
```

If you are using HTML5 mode you must ensure [$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode) is set so `$location` works properly.

If you are not using HTML5 mode (which is the case here); then you'll need to drop to [traditional javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to get the URL, since you are not using Angular routing in the first place:

```
// given url http://blo.c/news
var path = window.location.pathname;
// => "/news"
```

You might choose to inject [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) instead of using `window` directly, this is only a thin wrapper over the native `window` object but facilitates testing.

Comment: I get nothing in `console.log(path)`

Comment: Have you got `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`? If you haven't it will still expect a # in the URL. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode

Comment: No I can not use html5 true because my application was build not only on Angular JS, so also work PHP URI

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$location.path` function to get the url. To get what's after the url, use `split`

```
$location.path.split(/\{1}/)[1]
```

Comment: `TypeError: $location.path.split is not a function`. Also what is `[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const URL = '/seg1/?key=value';
$location.path();// will return URI segment (in above URL it returns /seg1 ).

$location.search(); // getter will fetch URL segment after ? symbol.  
//(in above URL it returns {key:value} object ).
```

Official Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location