# How to get base URL using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I need to get base URL using angular.js

Can any one help me on this?

I tried with different solutions and but I am not getting proper URL.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you injecting `$location` into your controller? Tried `$location.$$absUrl`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get URL segment in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871479/how-to-get-url-segment-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

The angular way of getting the url is using the $location service. You need to inject it wherever you need it (controller, another service, etc...)

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('controller', mainController);

/** @ngInject **/
function mainController($location){
  console.log($location) //prints all $location properties
  console.log($location.$$host) // prints 'stackoverflow.com'
  console.log($location.$$absUrl) // prints 'http://stackoverflow.com/exampleurl'
}
```

You can do it the non-angular way, using the global window.location object:

```
console.log(location.href) // prints 'http://stackoverflow.com/exampleurl'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How do i get the same using AngularJS 6+ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the base URL in the browser using Javascript you can use:

`window.location.origin`

Or to get an object of all parts use:

`window.location`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your info.